# If in_array option selected, inside foreach

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code which create some select fields:

```
$arrLanguages = array('en','fr','it','de','es','zh','ru','ro');
$arrFavLang   = array('fr','en','ru');
$countFav     = count($arrFavLang);

for($i=0;$i<$countFav;$i++) {
  echo '<select name="language[]">'."\n";
  foreach($arrLanguages as $language) {
    echo '  <option value="'.$language.'">'.$language.'</option>'."\n";
  }
  echo '</select>'."\n";
}
```

So I obtain this HTML repeated three times

```
<select name="language[]">
  <option value="en">en</option>
  <option value="fr">fr</option>
  <option value="it">it</option>
  <option value="de">de</option>
  <option value="es">es</option>
  <option value="zh">zh</option>
  <option value="ru">ru</option>
  <option value="ro">ro</option>
</select>
```

But I need to obtain selected field in this way

```
<select name="language[]">
  <option value="en">en</option>
  <option value="fr" selected>fr</option>
  <option value="it">it</option>
  [CUT]
</select>
<select name="language[]">
  <option value="en" selected>en</option>
  <option value="fr">fr</option>
  [CUT]
</select>
<select name="language[]">
  [CUT]
  <option value="zh">zh</option>
  <option value="ru" selected>ru</option>
  <option value="ro">ro</option>
</select>
```

Can you help me?

Comment: What you want is static ?

Comment: Select values from `$arrFavLang` ?

Comment: @zlen no, everything is dynamic.

Comment: @FLefèvre I don't understand what you mean

I need to create some select with all options, but if one option is selected, select it.

Comment: You have the current `$language`, you have the list number `$i`, you also have an array with your favorite languages `$arrFavLang`. Somewhere you need to echo `selected` when `$language` is equal to `$arrFavLang[$i]`. Try, and come back if you have a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it still make sense

```
$arrLanguages = array('en','fr','it','de','es','zh','ru','ro');
$arrFavLang   = array('fr','en','ru');
$countFav     = count($arrFavLang);

foreach($arrFavLang as $index => $selected) {
  echo '<select name="language[]">'."\n";
  foreach($arrLanguages as $language) {
    echo '  <option value="'.$language.'" ' . ($selected == $language ? "selected" : "") . ''>'.$language.'</option>'."\n";
  }
  echo '</select>'."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using this `in_array` method.

```
$arrLanguages = array('en','fr','it','de','es','zh','ru','ro');
  $arrFavLang   = array('fr','en','ru');

  foreach($arrFavLang as $index => $selected) {
    echo '<select name="language[]">'."\n";

    foreach($arrLanguages as $language) {
       echo '  <option value="'.$language.'" ' . 
        (in_array($language,$arrFavLang)? "selected" : "") . 
        '>'.$language.'</option>'."\n";
    }

    echo '</select>'."\n";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

still PHP not fancy, hope it answers the question

```
$arrLanguages = array('en','fr','it','de','es','zh','ru','ro');
$arrFavLang   = array('fr','en','ru');

buildSelect($arrFavLang[0],$arrLanguages);

buildSelect($arrFavLang[1],$arrLanguages);

buildSelect($arrFavLang[2],$arrLanguages);

function buildSelect( $selected, $arr){
  echo '<select name="language[]">'."\n";
  foreach($arr as $language) {
    if ($language==$selected) {  
        echo '  <option value="'.$language.'" selected>'.$language.'</option>'."\n";
    } else {
        echo '  <option value="'.$language.'">'.$language.'</option>'."\n";
    }
  }
  echo '</select>'."\n";
}
```